# Too many sites on apache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, django, mod-wsgi

I have a server with too many virtual hosts, about 500 virtual hosts, half of this with SSL.

All this hosts are served with mod_wsgi for Django applications.

I notice that after a certain number of virtual hosts all my server stops to work and all the sites crashes, I can handle this lowering the number of threads for each virtual hosts with this line:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess my.domain python-home=/var/www/env python-path=/var/www/my_app threads=1
```

The apache is crashing when reach about 1300 threads (when I check in htop).
The error log of apache indicates that the module Django is no found, but this is not the real error, because everything is OK e just happens when the number of vhosts is too high.
So I think I'm reaching some kind of limit with process or threads in Linux.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4, and have enough RAM and CPU, the server has 4 GB of RAM and is using just 2 GB, the average CPU is 10 to 20%.

I yet check my threads-max limit with:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
30893
```

What can I do to increase the capacity of virtualhosts in my apache without creating another server.

Comment: Try use nginx .. it's faster and can handle big job

Comment: Nginx is just a webserver. For django o need a wsgi server too like gunicorn, for hundreds of sites this doenst escale very well I will need 10 times more resources than apache with mod_wsgi.

Comment: i would suggest if you really have such massive count to scale via nginx or haproxy on more as one Server, however i think you will limited by open files or so due its default belongs about 1024

Comment: Please take a look on this article mentioning the finetuning of the memory - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293333/django-memory-usage-going-up-with-every-request and
https://serverfault.com/questions/289894/how-can-i-track-down-a-memory-leak-with-wsgi-django-php-and-apache2

Comment: "ave enough RAM and CPU." - define. Literally I would say that you have a ressource problem and give zero information relevant to the question.

Comment: Can you share crash msg with exact errors?

Comment: Just add more information to topic

Comment: I dont have memory and CPU problem, Im using AWS and increase to a better instance was the first thing I tried, this is not the problem.

Answer (score 5):

**1.** You might have more files open then you think. A way to tell (approximately) is:

*lsof -u www-data | wc -l*

**2.** try to increase stack size. Look how much current with

*ulimit -s*

and set new value with

*ulimit -s value*

---

ps. try these settings for 100k threads ability:

ulimit -s  256

ulimit -i  120000

echo 120000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

echo 600000 > /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count

echo 200000 > /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max

/etc/systemd/logind.conf: UserTasksMax=100000

Comment: Ok, I will try it.

Comment: My lsof command return a number of 18398, and ulimit -s 8192

Comment: When using ulimit -s 256 I have a Segmentation fault when starting apache service: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Looks like this is working, I just modified the hosts to use from 1 thread to 10 each and is working, but I made a few adjustments: just set the ulimit -s 120000
And increase the max number of files to 999999. How I can make this properties to remain after reboot?

Comment: /etc/sysctl.conf & /etc/security/limits.conf

Answer (score 0):

In your position, considering that amount of virtual hosts, I would split that load amongst at least a couple servers using a load balancer and a reverse proxy.